# Query for array of elements inside JSON type in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to test out the json type in PostgreSQL 11.22.
I have a json column called data in a table called customer. The JSON looks something like this:

```
postgres=# select * from customer ;
-[ RECORD 1 ]-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id          | 12
name        | Joseph
data        | [{"index":0,"address":"NewYork","contact":"0123456789"},{"index":0,"address":"UK","contact":"9876543210"}]
created     | 2024-03-17 16:30:32
```

Here I want to get the count of the number of rows if contact = '0123456789'
So, when I have passed the static value "0123456789" then the below query works for me

```
select count(*) from customer where data::jsonb @> '[{"contact": "0123456789"}]';
```

But, If the 'contact' key value is passed as a variable (as a runtime) then how it will work? Below is the trigger function where OLD.name is passed as a runtime value that they have. So how do we get the count?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger_validate() RETURNS trigger 
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$ 
DECLARE active_customer bigint; 
BEGIN 
   SELECT count(*) 
   FROM customer 
   WHERE data->>'contact'=OLD.name INTO active_customer; 
   IF active_customer > 0 THEN 
     RAISE EXCEPTION 'This is an entry found'; 
   END IF ; 
RETURN OLD; 
END;
```

Comment: passed where at runtime?

Comment: please add new information to your question

Comment: Postgres 11 has reached EOL in 2023. Upgrade to a [current version](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/).

Comment: Why do you have to cast `data::jsonb`? That column should be type `jsonb` to begin with. Please disclose  table definition (`CREATE TABLE`), the `CREATE TRIGGER` statement, and cardinalities of involved tables. Finally, why not have dedicated `text` columns for `contact` and `address`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is - a rework of your trigger function using a query that is very similar to your initial one, using `jsonb_build_array` and `jsonb_build_object`. Please note that you do not need the `active_customer` counter variable as you may use `exists` instead.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger_validate() RETURNS trigger 
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$ 
begin 
 if exists (
  select from customer 
  where data::jsonb @> jsonb_build_array(jsonb_build_object(
    'contact', OLD.name,
    'address', OLD.address))
 ) then
   raise exception 'This is an entry found'; 
 end if;
 return OLD; 
end; $$;
```

Unrelated but it would be better to have the `data` table column of type JSONB. It seems to not be the case since you cast it to JSONB in your examples.

Comment: One more query how do we use it if we want to include the address as an AND operator same in where condition? Like - 

`'address', OLD.address `

Comment: I think it will work if we want to satisfy both conditions of 'contact' AND 'address' matching -
`jsonb_build_array(jsonb_build_object('contact', OLD.name, 'address', OLD.address))`.

Comment: Yes it will. Answer updated with the new requirement.